# Python - Cant get minimum value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and i am trying to find minimum value but i have problem

```
def findminimum():
    data = input("")
    numberlist = []
    minumum = 0
    for data in data.splitlines():
        for numbers in data.split(" "):
            numberlist.append(numbers)
            minumum = min(numberlist)
    return minumum


    for i in range(0, times):
        print(findminimum(), end=" ")
```

When the data is 20 - 30 or 98 - 99 it returns the minimum value without problem but when i try to enter like 99 - 100, it returns 100

Comment: You're processing strings, not numbers, and `'100' < '99'` lexicographically.

Comment: so i need to convert to int ?

Comment: I should think so, yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns '100' because **you are working with strings**...  and strings are sorted **lexicographically**, which means that 1 goes before 9, in this case for example..

"1"

"10"

"100"

"4"

"40000"

"9"

Try converting to int and comparing again ;) you will do it this way

I hope this helps